# How to import CSV with a natural primary key into mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have a large CSV file (100M), which I wish to import into mongodb.

So, I have set out to explore my options with a small sample CSV. The mongoimport command works fine

```
mongoimport.exe -d mydb -c mycoll --type csv --file .\aaa.csv --headerline --stopOnError
```

but it creates the `_id` keys of type `ObjectId`. Now each record in the CSV contains a natural primary key, which I want to become the `_id` in mongo.

How do I do it for the import?

**EDIT**

The top two lines are:

```
id,aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff,ggg,hhh,iii,jjj,kkk,lll,mmm,nnn,ooo,ppp,qqq,rrr,sss,ttt,uuu,vvv,www,xxx,yyy,zzz,q11,q22,q33,q44,q55,q66,q77,q88
72184515,4522534,"xo xo","2011-08-01 00:00:00","here",4848,4185,100,"xa xa","oops","yep",39.0797,-94.4067,"aha","qw","er","ty","opo",39.1029,-94.3826,2.06146,2,"q",1,"w","e","r","t","y","a","s","d","r","12787",""
```

The `id` column should become the `_id`.

Comment: Post top part of your csv (with header)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the header line of your .csv file, simply change "id" to "_id".

When you use mongoimport, you may find that it is a little limiting because it only creates data types of strings or numbers.  The official recommendation for importing data from CSV files is to write your own script that will create documents containing the correct format and data types to fit your application.

However, if your .csv file contains only strings and numbers, then changing the header file should suffice.

Comment: Note that current versions of `mongoimport` can now correctly import decimal numbers as Double